# How to pass Linq Result to Extension Method in c# , error message: Cannot Convert from Anonymous type to DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, extension-methods

Below is my Linq Query, I am creating Extension method for my Model.

```
  var result = (from de in objEntities.Devices.AsEnumerable()
                          join ds in objEntities.DataSources
                          on de.DataSourceID equals ds.DataSourceID
                          where de.Name == DeviceId && ds.Deleted == false
                          select new  { DeviceName = de.Name, DataSourceName= ds.Name,Instance= ds.Instance }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Here how to pass Linq Result to Extension Method

```
objDTO= AuthenticationDTOTransformers.ToDTO(result);
```

Extension Method

```
public static class AuthenticationDTOTransformers
    {
        public static AuthenticationDTO ToDTO(this AuthenticateModel model)
        {
            if (model == null) { return null; }
            var dto = new AuthenticationDTO();
            ToDTO(model, dto);
            return dto;
        }
}
```

**Error:**

**Cannot Convert from Anonymous type to DTO**

[image]

Comment: Your LINQ creates an anonymous object, not an `AuthenticateModel`. Also, you're not using it like an extension method, though hopefully that was for debugging purposes.

Comment: Please provide the text of the error message as text, in the body of your question.

Comment: It is literally telling you what the issue is man. Only if all error messages were this informative.

Comment: Why my question was voted Negative ?

Comment: @ShakeerHussain See my previous comment.

Comment: I have given a screen shot. is there any difficulty to view to error screen shot

Comment: Yes, it's *much* harder to deal with a picture of the error message than the actual error message, but that said, the error message *is telling you what's wrong*.

Comment: Updated error message

Comment: @ShakeerHussain Kindly put the entire error message in the question, as text. That's a very simple request. Screenshots are not searchable. They are not easily readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message is self-explanatory,you are passing anonymous type to the method and thus the error. Create a custom type and pass it like this:-

```
class Device
{
    public string DeviceName  {get; set; }
    public string DataSourceName{get; set; }
    public string Instance{get; set; }
}
```

In your query, project the type:-

```
select new Device { DeviceName = de.Name, DataSourceName= ds.Name,Instance= ds.Instance }
```

Finally your method should look like this:-

```
 public static AuthenticationDTO ToDTO(this AuthenticateModel model, Device device)
```

As per above definition, you can call `ToDTO` method on an `AuthenticateModel` object and pass the `Device` object as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than returning anonymous type from select, you need to return a type which you want to extend. Here you are extending  AuthenticateMode class so return AuthenticateMode instance from select as below.

```
var result = (from de in objEntities.Devices.AsEnumerable()
                      join ds in objEntities.DataSources 
                      on de.DataSourceID equals ds.DataSourceID
                      where de.Name == DeviceId && ds.Deleted == false
                      select new AuthenticateMode { DeviceName = de.Name, DataSourceName = ds.Name, Instance = ds.Instance })
                      .SingleOrDefault();
```

Then call your extension method as

```
objDTO = result.ToDTO();
```